# Delphi Code Completion Fails

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, code-completion

We use Embarcadero Delphi 2010 and recently a change was made to one of the units of a medium-sized project, causing code completion to stop working completely -- but only inside this project, it still works fine in other projects.  Puzzled, I searched the interwebs for clues on what exactly could make this happen, but my search wasn't too successful.

From what I gathered, it looks like IDE has a few parsers/compilers that work completely separated from one another, which makes it entirely possible that the faster code-completion compiler could fail where the main compiler would not.  Which is exactly what's happening to my project.

My question: Is there a way to find out WHERE exactly the Code Insight/Code Completion compiler is failing?  Does the IDE keep a log of on-the-fly parsing/compilations anywhere?

Comment: I'd say, check your #defines

Comment: @PieterB Which #defines?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've had problems with codecompletion when I used #ifdefs and the code without ifdefs wouldn't be logical.

Comment: @Pieter: Thanks!  Done that already. I also checked for other occurrences that are known to cause trouble to the code completion engine, such as missing semicolons in the last line of a try-finally block or duplicate {$R *.res} items.

Comment: @PieterB Delphi does not use #define or #ifdef. Are you thinking of a different language?

Comment: I think he meant in general terms.  I did check for rogue {$IFDEF...} and {.$DEFINE...} items.

Comment: @user1595471 Why are you doing checks like that? You say that a change was made that brought this on. Well, your version control system will be able to isolate that change. Please tell me you have version control.

Comment: @David: Yes, I can (and did) restore the project files to earlier versions, but that is just adding more confusion to my brain.  My findings are contradictory.  For example:  1) Other existing projects do not exhibit this behavior, as I mentioned, nor do new projects.   But 2) If I restore this particular project to a couple of versions ago when I *know* code completion was working flawlessly, the problem should go away -- but isn't.   As you see, #1 points to a project change issue, while #2 points to a generic IDE problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry I should have clearer (and use $ instead of #), I was talking about the compiler directives {$IFDEF...} and {.$DEFINE...}

Comment: Does the project build?

Comment: @Marcus: Yes, Build All works, and I even went through the list of hints and warnings and removed some unused code to make the compiler gods calmer.  Find Declaration works too, which means there's *some* parsing occurring.

Comment: Have you deleted all auxiliary files? Create a new working copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to find out WHERE exactly the Code Insight/Code Completion compiler is failing?

Not readily, not without debugging the IDE.

> Does the IDE keep a log of on-the-fly parsing/compilations anywhere?

No.

---

I suggest that you install Andy Hausladen's IDEFixPack. If that does not help then use your revision control to isolate the code change that causes the problem. And find a different way to write that code that happens not to bork code completion. Trial and error is likely to be the most productive method here, much as I hate to say that.

Comment: Thanks for the IDEFixPack idea.  Unfortunately, upon installation I could no longer build my project.  It failed immediately with an Access Violation in the IDEFixPack DLL file.  Glad the uninstall worked.  :-)

Comment: I was looking for an answer that started with "Yes" LOL.  JK, I appreciate your response. I guess I'll have to give up and start pressing the bosses here for a compiler upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: May I humbly suggest you consider moving up to XE5?  2010 is not a very stable version.  XE, XE2 and XE5 are all far more stable and have many compiler and IDE bug fixes not in 2010. Are all code completion and error insight bugs fixed? No. But many many bugs are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem using Delphi 10.2.  After a lot of research I found that I had inadvertently declared a variable in a type section with an end; following on the next line.  Removing the errors restored the code completion function.  So I would recommend combing the interface for an error or restoring a backup from the directory history.